# How to disaggregate a data frame consisting of list of lists

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregation

If I construct a data frame as

```
# constructing df
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("A",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
#c <- c("ir", "ir", "br", "ir", "us", "us", "ir", "br")
c <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I can aggregate that via:

```
df_red <- aggregate(list(track = c), df[,c("a", "b")], '[')
```

What is the best way to disaggregate that back to what it was before?

IN another words, how can I convert this:

```
  a b   track
1 A 1    1, 2
2 B 1    4, 4
3 A 2 3, 4, 5
4 B 4       4
```

to this:

```
  a b c
1 A 1 1
2 A 1 2
3 A 2 3
4 B 4 4
5 B 1 4
6 B 1 4
7 A 2 4
8 A 2 5
```

Comment: In base R, you could do `cbind(df_red[rep(seq_along(df_red$track), lengths(df_red$track)), 1:2], track=unlist(df_red$track))`.

Comment: Try with `library(tidyr);unnest(df_read)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) unnest** Try `unnest` like this:

```
library(tidyr)

df_red %>% unnest
```

or

```
unnest(df_red)
```

**2) base** Here is a base solution:

```
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, c(data.frame, df_red)))
```

**3) separate_rows** Also note that if you wanted to aggregate into a string rather than into a vector we could have this pair:

```
library(tidyr)

ag_s <- aggregate(list(track = c), df[c("a", "b")], toString)

ag_s %>% separate_rows(track)
```